# Add class on click and then remove class on delay (timeout function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jimdo but i have a head area where i be able to change all codes and everything works fine but this cool timeout feature. Any help would be great!

This is my code which adds a class to an animated svg image which status is display:none. With a click on a download button the svg image changes to display:block and runs 3 times and fades out after 3 second. So far so good. What i want is that the added class "s-dwlnd" will be removed after the svg fades out. Exactly after 3 seconds to be correct :) ... Is there a way to do this? To add a working timeout function to my existing code? Not all codes working with Jimdo :(

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".dwlnd-trg" ).click(function() {
    $( ".dwlnd" ).addClass( "s-dwlnd" );
});});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, something like this should work:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".dwlnd-trg" ).click(function() {
        $( ".dwlnd" ).addClass( "s-dwlnd" );

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".dwlnd").removeClass("s-dwlnd");
        }, 3000); // Delay of 3 seconds
    });
});
```

Comment: btw, is there a way to put mutiple classes in one code? I have many of those ".dwlnd-trg" classes. Like ".dwlnd-trg2",  ".dwlnd-trg3"  ".dwlnd-trg4" and ".dwlnd", ".dwlnd2", ".dwlnd3", ".dwlnd4" and so on. Only ".s-dwlnd" stays always the same because this is the class which displays the animated svg image. At the moment i have copied and pasted your working code in jimdos head and it's great but would it be much cleaner if it's not 4, 6 or soon 8 instead of one good looking code :) I tried to but without success...